# Blender could not convert the .blend file to FBX file

Tags: unity

I have blender 2.83.15, but when I go to unity and let it import and do its thing, I get the error: "Blender could not convert the .blend file to FBX file. You need to use Blender 2.45-2.49 or 2.58 and later versions for direct Blender import to work."

But I have 2.83.15, does anyone know why this is?

[image: This is my truck that I am making]

Comment: I don't know Unity at all, but I'd have thought that mention of Blender versions that old in its error reports means that it must be a very old version. Have you tried exporting using an up to date version of Blender (currently 3.3)?

Comment: uhm no actually, i don't think my school will let my update, sadly.

Comment: Blender 2.83 is no longer supported so I'm afraid you're going to be out of luck unless anyone else here has seen the problem before.

Comment: Oh, ok. I guess i'll have to find out myself then?

Comment: @JohnEason In the question I have added a picture of an error that I get when I try exporting the file to a .FBX file.

Comment: No idea I'm afraid. I don't "speak" Blender python, but that appears to be an error in Blender's FBX exporter so if it's creating incorrect code in the FBX file it's not surprising that Unity can't read it.

Comment: What would it be then? how could I fix it?

Comment: No idea I'm afraid. As I said I don't understand Python. The closest I can get is to say that something in the export_fbx_bin.py python file doesn't like something in the Blender file that it's trying to export and is throwing an error.

Comment: Ok cool, sounds good :|